# Propane water heater pilot heater goes out with main burner

Tags: water-heater, pilot-light

I have a Whirlpool LP water heater model L30S61. The pilot light lights easily and the main burner comes on and heats the water. When the burner goes out so does the pilot light. I replaced the thermopile assembly but the problem persists. I tested the thermal switch and the valves, all good. Was thinking about replacing the control board, but wanted to see if the problem could be something else first. Another thread suggested the gas line pressure regulator could be bad, but wouldn't that create the same effect on the furnace that gets fuel from the same source?

Comment: What is the colour of both flames?  They should be blue with maybe a tiny bit of yellow at the tip of the flame.  Usually replacing parts to see if it fixes the problem can start to get expensive.